# Using constructor where function expected

Tags: scala, constructor, higher-order-functions

Having two simple classes taking `Int` as an argument:

```
case class Foo(i: Int)
     class Bar(j: Int)
```

I can say:

```
List(1,2,3) map Foo
```

Which works fine and is equivalent to a bit more verbose:

```
List(1,2,3) map {Foo(_)}
```

However `Bar` (because it is not a case class?) cannot be used in the same construct:

```
List(1,2,3) map Bar

  error: not found: value Bar
          List(1,2,3) map Bar
                          ^
```

Is there some special syntax to reference any constructor and take advantage of eta expansion? `List(1,2,3) map {new Bar(_)}` seems a bit more verbose compared to `Foo`.

Comment: Eta expansion is something that happen to methods. Note that a constructor is not a method.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral What exactly is a constructor ?

Comment: @AshkanKh.Nazary A constructor is a sequence of instructions that initializes a newly allocated object.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral And that is not a method or a function ? You can't call it explicitly or pass it around or apply eta expansion on it to turn it into a function ?

Comment: @AshkanKh.Nazary No, you can't. Try `new String _`, for example. It is also different at the bytecode level, and there's all sort of differences in JVM expectations between methods and constructors.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Thanks for the comments. Any particular reason the syntax for defining a constructor so closely resembles a method definition ?

Comment: @AshkanKh.Nazary The more closely they resemble each other, the less things to recall. That can backfire when people assume things are equal when they aren't, but languages are a popularity contest, and first impressions count more than anywhere else I know. That said, the syntax isn't actually very close in Scala: the constructor in Scala is the body of the class. The secondary constructors, which do look like methods, are just pre and post-processing around the main constructor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works in the former case, because companion object of a case class extends appropriate `FunctionN` trait. (`object Foo extends (Int => Foo)` in your example.) For non-case classes, you could do this manually:

```
scala> class Bar(i: Int)
defined class Bar

scala> class Bar(i: Int); object Bar extends (Int => Bar) { def apply(i: Int) = new Bar(i) }
defined class Bar
defined module Bar

scala> List(2, 3) map Bar
res17: List[Bar] = List(Bar@1f99e90, Bar@1191056)
```

IMO it's better to go with `new Bar(_)` as this extra boilerplate might not be worth the little concision achieved.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware that a case class extends `FunctionN`. I remember a SO answer where all automatic features of case classes are listed but don't remember that issue mentioned.

Comment: case classes don't. Their companion objects do.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Foo` is a case class there is also a companion object called `Foo`, which implements the `Function1` interface (had the constructor taken three arguments it would have been the `Function3` interface).