# What is the default `apply` method of an `object`?

Tags: scala, object, apply

Assume, we have the following definitions:

```
scala> trait T
defined trait T

scala> object A extends T
defined module A
```

Then we can create an object with type `T` with:

```
scala> val t: T = A
t: T = A$@98b13b
```

No `new` keyword is used here, so therefore an `apply` method is used here.
But we did not define an `apply` method so far, so I guess a default `apply` method is used here ? But what does it look like ?

**UPDATE 1:**

When assigning an variable of type `A` with the same, an error will be thrown:

```
scala> val a: A = A
<console>:9: error: not found: type A
       val a: A = A
              ^
```

Why is the same 'trick' not working here ? What is the difference ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`A` is an `object`, not a `class`, thus you don't need to create an instance of it - it is basically a singleton. Therefore no `new` is required. `apply` is not involed here.

It's a bit different with `case class`es:

```
case class C(x: Int)
val c = C(10)
```

This time `new` operator wasn't used as well but new object was created - and this time `apply()` is involved. Basically when you create a `case class`, companion object is created as well with `apply` method implemented for your convinience (see: [Using constructor where function expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695515)):

```
val c = C.apply(10)
```

Comment: Thank you. When I understand you right, the (singleton) object of `A` is already a full object. But in another example (see Update 1) there will be an error thrown when using the object `A` as a normal object. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood: this is technically a separate question, but whatever. Since `A` is an object (think: singleton) there is no point in creating variables of it or passing it as parameter (see: `def foo(a: A)`). You can always access it by simply using `A`.

Answer (score 4):

Your object `A` is not a type, therefore you cannot use it in a type ascription.

```
val a: T = A
```

and

```
val a: A.type = A
```

work.

`T` is the widened type of the trait you know that `A` inherited, `A.type` is the narrow type of the singleton `object`.

Comment: Thank you, now I undertand. Do you know where I can find more information about `A.type` ? This is new to me.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood There's nothing much to it. `A.type` is a singleton type. If I do `val a = "abc"; val b: a.type = a`, I'm saying `b` is not simply a `String`, but it's actually the exact same thing as `a`. It's useful sometimes. If you want more information, ask another question. It's free! :-)